# How to execute a function at a specified time set dynamically by user in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, pdf, timer

I have a function in java which contains the code to generate the pdf file and save into the system local disk.Now as per my requirement i have to make a jsp page which contains a form from where user can dynamically set the date and time on which he needs pdf to be generated.Now pdf should be generated as per the user input given and user input is dynamic in nature it can be changed..

For example ..

Suppose user has set pdf to be created on 15 of every month at 10:00 am..Then this time it should generate the pdf on 15 at 10:00a am..

Now if his requirement change he can set it to 10 of every month at 10:00 am ..and so on..

I am not able to get the way to proceed..

Here is my pdf generation code in POJO file..

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("D://timer.pdf"));
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);

        //Inserting Table in PDF
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Java4s.com"));

        cell.setColspan(3);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.setPadding(10.0f);
        cell.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(140, 221, 8));

        table.addCell(cell);

        table.addCell("Name");
        table.addCell("Address");
        table.addCell("Country");
        table.addCell("Java4s");
        table.addCell("NC");
        table.addCell("United States");
        table.setSpacingBefore(30.0f);       // Space Before table starts, like margin-top in CSS
        table.setSpacingAfter(30.0f);        // Space After table starts, like margin-Bottom in CSS                                       

        //Inserting List in PDF
        List list = new List(true, 30);
        list.add(new ListItem("Java4s"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Php4s"));
        list.add(new ListItem("Some Thing..."));

        //Text formating in PDF
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Welecome To Java4s Programming Blog...");
        chunk.setUnderline(+1f, -2f);//1st co-ordinate is for line width,2nd is space between
        Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk("Php4s.com");
        chunk1.setUnderline(+4f, -8f);
        chunk1.setBackground(new BaseColor(17, 46, 193));

        //Now Insert Every Thing Into PDF Document
        document.open();//PDF document opened........                  
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);   //Something like in HTML :-)
        document.add(new Paragraph("Dear Java4s.com"));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Document Generated On - " + new Date().toString()));
        document.add(table);
        document.add(chunk);
        document.add(chunk1);
        document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);   //Something like in HTML :-)                             
        document.newPage();            //Opened new page
        document.add(list);            //In the new page we are going to add list
        document.close();

        file.close();

        System.out.println("Pdf created successfully..");
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class. There is a lot of example on [this site](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html).

As someone mentioned in the comments that going with [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) would be better. (The javadoc already has a tutorial on that subject.)

Comment: I think a `ScheduledExecutorService` is more applicable here as then you have a `Future` that allows you to control and monitor the task.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Please provide me a link or a code snippet sir I am very new to this..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer and Task classes which are of java

Comment: I think a `ScheduledExecutorService` is more applicable here as then you have a `Future` that allows you to control and monitor the task.